# Can I create an abstract class to use with a 3rd part classes?

Tags: c#

I am working with a large 3rd party API and in this API I have hundreds of objects each with a good deal of properties inside it.

I have to perform the basic CRUD operations through the API on these objects.

Say I have the following 3rd party class:

3rd party class:

```
public class ThirdPartyObject1
    {
        public string Field1;
        public string Field2;
        public string Field3;
        public string Field4;
        // etc.....
    }
```

My first attempt I tried the following:

I created my own interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    object LoadObject(string param);
    void DeleteObject(string param);
    object UpdateObject(string param);
}
```

and it's own class:

```
public class MyClass1 : ThirdPartyObject1, IMyInterface
{
    public object LoadObject(string param)
    { // Load object }

    public void DeleteObject(string param)
    { // Deleteobject }

    public object UpdateObject(string param)
    { // Load object }

}
```

However it does not appear that this is a good approach, for I will need to write code to handle the CRUD operations for each class. 
(Not to mention creating new classes comprised of the various 3rd party classes)

I can create an abstract class that handles the CRUD operations, but how would I implement the 3rd party class off of that abstract class?

Comment: Is it the same code for all classes for the CRUD operations?

Comment: The read will probably not be for the api has a method to read each object. The other methods (Delete for sure) should be a common enough approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own inheritors:

```
public abstract class BaseMyThirdParty<T> where T : class
{
    public T OriginalObject { get; set; }

    public BaseMyThirdParty(T originalObject) {
      this.OriginalObject = originalObject;
    }

    public virtual T LoadObject(string param)
    { // Load object }

    public virtual void DeleteObject(string param)
    { // Deleteobject }

    public virtual T UpdateObject(string param)
    { // Update object }
}
```

And then make your "wrappers" with just what changed in them:

```
public class MyClass1 : BaseMyThirdParty<ThirdPartyObject1>
{
    public MyClass1(ThirdPartyObject1 originalObject)
      : base(originalObject) {}

    public override ThirdPartyObject1 LoadObject(string param)
    { 
      // Load object in a different way
    }   

    public ThirdPartyObject1 LoadObject(string param, string param2)
    { 
     // Load object with two different parameters 
    }   
}
```

Yes, you'd still need a wrapper for each type, but you can define the common functionality in the abstract base class, and use the concrete type for any extra functionality. If no other extra functionality is needed, you'd just need to have a file with several of these:

```
public class MyClass2 : BaseMyThirdParty<ThirdPartyObject2> 
{ 
    public MyClass2(ThirdPartyObject2 originalObject)
      : base(originalObject) {}
}
public class MyClass3 : BaseMyThirdParty<ThirdPartyObject3> { 
    public MyClass3(ThirdPartyObject3 originalObject) 
      : base(originalObject) {}
}
```

You could also have `BaseMyThirdParty` not be `abstract` and use the generic type directly if no additional functionality is needed normally.

All this said: I'm surprised a library with *hundreds* of different classes doesn't use a common base type or any kind of interfaces (at least for those classes that you'd do CRUD on)

--

### Update

I've updated the code to include the original type in the base class (which you pass on the constructor). This is one "easy" way to use the properties in the original object:

```
var myObj = new MyClass1(new ThirdPartyObject1());
myObj.OriginalObject.FieldWhatever;
```

Another way would be using a `DynamicObject` and have use the fields via reflection: I do not recommend this... you lose type-safety and intellisense and would more likely be slower... the code would be easier to write though.

Comment: I setup my abstract class and implemented as: public class MyCar : BaseThirdParty<ThirdPartyCar>

However the goal is still for me to use the existing properties in ThirdPartyCar, I would just like to add methods handle CRUD 

Am I overthinking things?  Maybe I should just create a CRUD class to handle what is similar and use the interface to handle the Load since each would be different anyway?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the base object to the abstract class. You'll need to pass its value somewhere (I've used the constructor, but you can pass it directly when creating a new class... for example: `var myCar = new MyCar() { OriginalObject = myThirdPartyCar);`, which would allow you not to write the constructor in each wrapper

Comment: Now, you could also just have three external functions (or extensions, like in the other answers) and not use inheritance at all. But again: if the types you are using don't have anything in common, neither of these will work for you. Again, I find it strange that a library with hundreds of types for doing CRUD on them don't have base classes or interfaces for those that share things in common, but I'm just trying to answer your question with the data you gave

Comment: I went with this approach, It will allow me to at least isolate the reads within the given class, plus it gets me thinking on how to use genrics moving forward (one place where I'm lacking).  The fact that this API has 500+ classes each with their own read methods won't make it easy but at least it is providing some structure to this application.

Comment: Generally, generics are good for specific classes that share things in common (like a base class, or interfaces). These kind of generic "catch all" interfaces are just ok IMO for abstract classes (or a very specific need). Btw, I updated my question with constructor chaining... don't know why I didn't write it like this on my last edit, but I probably need some rest :-) there you go. Also, I guess you could look at T4 templates to generate the wrapper code automatically if there are many of those classes that don't change behaviour from the `abstract` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using ExtensionMethods to handle this.  While it would be separate class but for coding it will look like it's part of the class

If you are going to make your own class for read then you could create an interface and limit the extension methods to that interface.  They way it's written now it would appear on all classes.

```
public static class ThridPArtyExtensionMethods
{
    public static object LoadObject<T>(this T thirdParty, string param)
        where T : class
    {
        return param; // obviously not right
    }

    public static void DeleteObject<T>(this T thirdParty, string param)
        where T : class
    {
    }

    public static object UpdateObject<T>(this T thirdParty, string param)
        where T : class
    {
        return param; // obviously not right
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to set an extension method for each of the 500+ classes that I'm trying to wrap?

Comment: @JDS no, you can make generic extensions (like he did on this answer). They'll work for any object that meets the constraints (in this case: every reference object). You'll see them in intellisense for every other class if you add the namespace or static class to your `usings` though